# QML Dynamic Load Window On Button Press, But Focus Instead If Exists

Tags: qt, qml

I have a button within my main ApplicationWindow (`root`) that dynamically loads and opens a second, different ApplicationWindow that is declared in a separate `.qml` file.

```
Button {
    id: btnLogger
    text: "Logger"
    onClicked: {
        var component = Qt.createComponent("logger.qml")
        var window    = component.createObject(logRoot)
        window.show()
    }
}
```

This works fine for opening a window when clicking the button. Subsequent clicks create further new windows.

My intent is that subsequent clicks should instead focus the preexisting window. If the new window is later closed, then clicking the button should revert back to opening the window.

i.e. if a window doesn't currently exist or exists but has been closed, create it and open it; else, focus it.

How would this be done from within `qml`? Alternatively, I am currently loading the application from a QQmlApplicationEngine in my `C++`, how could I use that to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Why did you think it should work like this? This code will work exactly as you wrote it - creates a component, instantiates and shows it (if that's `Window`). If you want this will focus an existing window you have to change the logic.

Comment: @folibis I understand that it wouldn't do what I wanted. I was showing what I currently had, and was asking what I would need to do to achieve the new functionality. Do you have an edit suggestion to help make the question clearer for yourself and others?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code for my comment above:

```
Button {
    id: btnLogger
    text: "Logger"
    property var wnd: undefined
    onClicked: {
        if(wnd == undefined)
        {
            var component = Qt.createComponent("logger.qml")
            wnd = component.createObject(logRoot);
            wnd.closing.connect(function() { btnLogger.wnd = undefined;});
            wnd.show();
        }
        else
        {
            wnd.requestActivate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That works well, thank you - but I'm going to clarify my question because it isn't quite everything.
If the user closes the window, then clicks the button again I'd like the window to be opened again: I've achieved this with `if (wnd.active) wnd.requestActivate(); else wnd.show();` , but I'd lvoe your opinion on this to then accept your answer.

Comment: just add an `onClosing` event handler, I've updated the answer. The same you can do with `Connections`.

Comment: Thats so much better than my solution! I guess it means now that the window is garbage collected after closing, unlike in my comment above where the window remains but is not active.